# Why doesn't the JVM simply terminate instead of throwing OOME?

Tags: java

If catching an `OutOfMemoryError` is highly discouraged, since you may not know the condition of the JVM after catching the error, why doesn't the JVM simply terminate and notify the user somehow instead of throwing the error?

Comment: If you don't the reason? How can you provide a solution?

Comment: Even though it normally terminates (i.e. is not considered recoverable) it is able to specify the reason (and perhaps location) of failure by throwing the OOM and unwinding.

Comment: Do you know, that you can use the option `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` to force the JVM to exit on out of memory errors?

Comment: Well let us say you got OME, but it was not printed on console (or) some where, but JVM quietly exit, then which way you lean to? Is it that your program exited because of everything went fine (or) outofmemoryerror?

Comment: @Nambari ok,it would notify the user somehow, I edited my question

Comment: "it would notify user somehow", any thoughts on what this somehow would be?

Comment: @Nambari I think it's not important, if you catch the error, you might not be able to do _anything_

Comment: I think point we need to concentrate on is, if we are not sure on which state JVM will be, then how can we expect that, it loads some other exception class and executes it to notify user?

Comment: @nosid I didn't know that, but it seems even Google hardly knows it

Comment: It does 'notify the user somehow', with an exception. Why dream up another mechanism when one already exists?

Comment: @EJB I think exceptions are meant to be for programmers

Comment: Exactly, and that's why it throws an exception, so the programmer can catch it. The programmer can't catch a notification to the user.

Comment: @EJP it's an error `... that a reasonable application should not try to catch.`, but then, why give a chance to catch it?

Comment: Actually Java 8u92 offers `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` which "simply terminates". Notifying is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is no single standard way to report an error condition to the user.  Throwing an Error allows the object to be caught at the top level, and the report of the condition made however it may be appropriate (console message, write to a log file, displaying a dialog, etc) prior to termination.  The documentation states that reasonable applications should not catch Errors, which is true: the best way for them to be handled is in framework code, as there is very little (although not zero) variation in how they can be handled.  Specifically, they cannot realistically be *recovered from*, which is why most application authors attempt to catch them.

Update: there is another reason, too.  Throwing an error does not only allow the error to be caught: it also causes code in "finally" blocks to be executed.  As these blocks could include critical cleanup code, it is important that they are allowed to run before the application is terminated.

Answer (score 4):

Because you could know what to do and how to do it.

Example:  your code (attempts to) create an array with several dozen million elements (depending on some input).  Any `OutOfMemoryException` will most probably be for this reason.  In particular, you can put **only** the array creation in a try/catch block.  After the exception, memory will most probably be in a pretty decent level (the array is either completely allocated, or not allocated at all).  Your program can continue executing.  Even produce an error message, send an e-mail, or take any other corrective actions and proceed with the next input (from a user, a batch, etc).

That kind of discouragement notes are usually targeted at the beginner/average developer.  One that would try to catch the exception at the top level of the program, for example, where there is no detail about what triggered it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a chance of dumping the data, or determine the reason of the OOME in other ways when the application is not terminated.

If it is uncaught, it terminates the THREAD from which the error was initiated. Other threads keep running just fine, unless of course they cause OutOfMemoryErrors too.

If you want to kill your JVM no matter what because you suspect it can be in an inconsistent state, add this to your java options:

`-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"`

Answer (score 1):

Throwables (Exceptions, Errors) are the standard way for JVM to notify users about problems. It's not a thing of catching it, but to have a log about what happened, where and when. Creating some method to perform a logic after an OOM is not a sure thing, since the JVM status could be inconsistent, and the notification logic may never be executed.

Besides, as a complimentary action, you can also request that OOM errors generate a dump, which you can review later (using dump analizers) and search for memory leaks in your applications, using

`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`

Answer (score 0):

By throwing an OutOfMemoryError, there is a chance that something somewhere might have enough memory to receive the exception and record the fact that it occurred (e.g. a logger, or stdout).  The program should probably then exit, rather than trying to continue on in a potentially invalid state.

Although this attempt to record/log the OutOfMemoryError might fail because the system is out of memory, there is also a good chance that it might succeed.  If the JVM summarily exited on OOM, there is zero chance of the problem cause being recorded.  A non-zero chance of recording the problem is better than zero chance of recording the problem.